# Chrome extension is showing error when migrated to manifest v3

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have specified a `host_permissions` and it is showing error when i migrated from manifest v2 to manifest v3.
**Warning i got**

```
⚠ Permission 'activeTab' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
```

The thing i specified in the manifest was

```
"host_permissions": ["activeTab"]
```

Can anyone explain what is the fix for this? though it is not making any issues, i want to fix that.
Thanks.

Comment: `activeTab` should be specified in `permissions` not `host_permissions`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh, i thought `host_permissions` is an upgrade for `permissions`, thanks for you comment, if you can put it as answer, i can mark it as answer